# xceed IntegerUpdown's TabIndex has no effect

Tags: wpf, tabindex, xceed

I have 4 `IntegerUpDowns` from the Xceed toolkit. The problem is that the navigation through Tab button does not work at all. I set `TabIndex`, `TabStop` properties, but no effect. Maybe somebody had this problem? Any help will be appreciate! Thanks a lot!

Here is a code:

```
<GroupBox Margin="20"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  Header="groupbox header text">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                            Margin="7"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="text1:" />
                    <xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="updown1"
                                        Width="50"
                                        Height="25"
                                        Margin="17,0,30,0"
                                        TabIndex="0"
                                        IsTabStop="True"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Increment="1"
                                        PreviewKeyDown="NumericUpDown_OnPreviewKeyDown"
                                        ValueChanged="Updown1_OnValueChanged"
                                        Value="{Binding Property1,
                                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="text2" />
                    <xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="updown2"
                                        Width="50"
                                        Height="25"
                                        Margin="43,0,0,0"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Increment="2"
                                        TabIndex="2"
                                        IsTabStop="True"
                                        PreviewKeyDown="NumericUpDown_OnPreviewKeyDown"
                                        Value="{Binding Property2,
                                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                            Margin="7,0,7,7"
                            Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="text3:" />
                    <xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="updown3"
                                        Width="50"
                                        Height="25"
                                        Margin="7,0,30,0"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Increment="1"
                                        TabIndex="1"
                                        IsTabStop="True"
                                        PreviewKeyDown="NumericUpDown_OnPreviewKeyDown"
                                        ValueChanged="Updown3_OnValueChanged"
                                        Value="{Binding Proeprty3,
                                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="text4:"/>
                    <xctk:IntegerUpDown Name="updown4"
                                        Width="50"
                                        Height="25"
                                        Margin="7,0,0,0"
                                        TabIndex="3"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        Increment="1"
                                        IsTabStop="True"
                                        PreviewKeyDown="NumericUpDown_OnPreviewKeyDown"
                                        Value="{Binding Property4,
                                                        Mode=TwoWay,
                                                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
```

Comment: It works for me. I am puzzled by the PreviewKeyDown handlers. Are you sure they do not intercept Tab?

Comment: @Dabblernl I removed PreviewKeyDown handlers - everything is working! Thank you!